# Laravel - How to render HTML in my view without escaping the enclosing tags?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, rendering

I want to render some HTML in my view but it is escaping the enclosing HTML and messing up my page.
Basically I have a list of posts and I want to show a preview of the next post. The data is stored in my table as a string with all html tags since it was made using an editor and saved as raw html. Even using html_entity_decode it messes up the formatting. Any ways to solve this?

Here's my current code. Again, rendering the HTML breaks the enclosing div (and the rest of the page). Not rendering the html doesn't look user friendly.

```
`<div class="post">
    <p class="content">
        {!! substr($post->content, 0, 250) !!}
    </p>
</div>`
```

I've tried this with no luck

```
`{{ html_entity_decode(substr($post->content, 0, 250)) }}`

`{!! substr($post->content, 0, 250) !!}`

`{!! html_entity_decode(substr($post->content, 0, 250)) !!}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why you are using substr? , try without it

Comment: @AliIsmaeel Because I only want to show a preview of the text, like a short description, since the real text is multiple paragraphs long

Comment: So that could be your problem. when you use `substr` you are taking the first 250 characters which include opening tags like `<p>` , but without closing tags, try without `substr`.